# Create temporary workvariable with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Problem: 
I have a list of ints and I want to get the numbers that exists two or more times.

```
List<int> firstList = new List<int> { 1, 1, 3 };
```

Expected Result:

```
{ 1 }
```

This can easily be done with LINQ.. For example this one

```
var result = firstList.Where(c => firstList.Count(d => c == d) > 1).Distinct();
```

Problem is that this does a more than one iteration. With a normal for loop we can reach a time of O(N)..

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
HashSet<int> doubles = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var v in firstList)
{
    if (!doubles.Contains(v))
        doubles.Add(v);
    else
        result.Add(v);
}
```

Which is what we want to do with linq aswel...

```
HashSet<int> doubles = new HashSet<int>();
var result = firstList.Where((c) => doubles.Contains(c) ? true : !doubles.Add(c)).ToList();
```

This is the only way I can think of..

**Question:**
Is there some way I can declare my "new HashSet" inside LINQ. Im thinking something like `firstList.Aggregate((c, d = new HashSet<int>) =>`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evelie, both of Eren's and John's answers are correct and they are the simplest you can get. In the 'pretty' syntax of LINQ, there's a `let` keyword that allows you to introduce something, but that's mostly is rewritten by the compiler in a similar way to the `var hashset` seen in Eren's post. Just as you cannot 'hide' the source `firstList`, you usually cannot hide other support variables. At least, in a **sane way**.

Insane ways exists. By insane I mean far less readable and obscure.

For example, let's rewrite Eren's example with variable hiding:

```
var firstList = new[] { 1, 1, 3 };

var result = Enumerable.Repeat(new { list = firstList, hash = new HashSet<int>() }, 1)
                .Select(anon => anon.list.Where(x => !anon.hash.Add(x)))
                .SelectMany(_ => _);
```

but was it worth it?

Also, please do not confine yourself to the standard LINQ operators. You may easily introduce your own:

```
public static class MyOps
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (var item in input)
            if (!hashSet.Add(item))
                yield return item;
    }
}

var firstList = new[] { 1, 1, 3 };

var result1 = firstList.FindDuplicates();
```

and, that's usually worth the small effort to wrap it into a new extension. Please note that all this code is almost identical with the previous ones presented by you and others. It is just "nicely wrapped" into either "variable-hider", or into "extension".

Edit: and yes, that's true, all the examples with hashset will return all duplicates. Instead of distinct'ing, you can do it by two hashsets: one for duplicate checking, and one for filtering duplicate-results.

```
public static class MyOps
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        var hashSet1 = new HashSet<T>();
        var hashSet2 = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (var item in input)
            if (!hashSet1.Add(item)) // note the negation
                if (hashSet2.Add(item)) // note NO negation
                    yield return item;
    }
}

var firstList = new[] { 1, 1, 3 };

var result1 = firstList.FindDuplicates();
```

But that's mostly what .distinct() would do anyways.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach would be:

```
var repeated = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .Select(g => g.Key);
```

That will only iterate once - it will be slightly less efficient than your hand-crafted solution, but should be pretty reasonable - and it's very simple.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I mean two or more times. However this would also be O(N)^2.. which is worse than O(N) scenario :(

Comment: @Evelie: What makes you think it would be O(N^2)? (Groups are implemented such that counting them is O(1).)

Comment: GroupBy will iterate entries in list. And then you have to iterate them all again ( inside every group ) to count them... Or at least thats what I would think.

Comment: This would make 2*N not N^2, but I suppose that GroupBy/IGrouping`2 uses List<> internally, which has the .Count amortized, so that'd be N+K where N is number of elements and K is number of distinct elements.. either way, O(N)

Comment: @Evelie: No, because the groups are stored as `List<T>` (or similar, anyway) - so counting a group is an O(1) operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet the "Count()" is a function, not a property as the list would have. This makes me belive that he will actually count the individuals. Requiring one complete iteration of all items. I might be wrong.

Comment: @John,@Evelie: even if counting were not amortized by List, it still would be O(N), because there are N elements to iterate in first pass, and **total** of N elements to count in the second pass (just splitted over K groups, but still, N in total). This makes N + a+b+c+d+...z, where a+b+c+...z == N, thus 2*N = O(N)..

Comment: @Evelie: You *are* wrong. Believe me, I've reimplemented LINQ to Objects personally :) `Count()` is optimized for any implementation of `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Good point - so it's fine in two different ways ;)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl for the sake of the argument we assume that he have to count every item. How can you get it to 2N here. I mean first iteration is N. Then second iteration ( the count) would also be N. N*N = n^2.

Comment: @Evelie: No, read quetzalcoatl's argument very carefully. Even if each `Count()` operation is O(X) where X is the size of the list, the *total* of all of those counts will only be the original N... so O(X1) + O(X2) + O(X3)... will just be O(N).

Comment: @JonSkeet I trust you. But is there someway I can confirm this?

Comment: @Evelie: The simplest way would be to test it with data sets of various sizes.

Comment: but why *N? it is not *N. Almost no group has N elements. If any group had N elements, all other groups would be EMPTY thus zero. Please do it by hand or on piece of paper, you will see. In second iteration, there indeed is K (K<=N) groups to count, but the COUNTS are far less than N. There is no K*N, and there is no N*N!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl we still to count every item in every group right? In my example we would have 2 groups. 1 group with 2 1s and one group with the 3. Counting all items in both group would be N. ( 3 ).

Comment: items = {1,1,3}; group1 = {1,1}; group2 = {3}. N=3. K=groups=2 < N. group1.count=2; group2.count=1; "total time" to count the groups = total time to visit every group and count it = total time to visit every element in every group = group1.count + group2.count = 3 === N. **just as you said**. But that's the **total** time of pass2. So, pass1 = N, and pass2 = N, so total time of operation is N+N=2*N, not N^2. Sorry, I will stop repeating it now. Do it by hand with seeds or stones, you will see.

Comment: Ah thanks for everything.I get the 2N now. Sorry if I seemed a bit stubborn :D

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do this (just a shorter way of what you're doing):

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
var filtered = firstList
    .Where(x =>
    {
        if (hashSet.Contains(x)) return true;
        hashSet.Add(x);
        return false;
    });
```

But I think it's best to avoid such side-effects and just use Jon Skeet's method above (safely assuming it's above :))

**Edit:**

Per Jon Skeet's comment below, this could even be shortened as:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
var filtered = firstList.Where(x => !hashSet.Add(x));
```

Note that you need to be careful about using this once. For example:

```
var list1 = filtered.ToList(); // correct result
var list2 = filtered.ToList(); // incorrect result (returns all numbers)
```

Comment: Yes but even here I have to declare the HashSet outside of my LINQ :(.

Comment: You don't even need the `if` or the `Contains` check - you can just use `.Where(x => !hashSet.Add(x))`

Comment: If there are 3 1s I would get 2 in the result without the ifcheck. You would have to use a distinct after to make that one work.

Comment: that's true. You can add `.Distinct()` after the `Where`.